# ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm getting the following stack trace...

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.findClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:148)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:131)
    org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:103)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2252)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2227)
    org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
    org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:143)
    org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:317)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1607)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1544)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    com.mydomain.GetController.getUser(GetController.java:20)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:947)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:878)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:946)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
```

When my Spring controller handles the connection:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) int id) {
        User user = null;

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        UserService userService = (UserService) context.getBean("userService");

        user = userService.getUser(id);
        context.close();

        return user;
    }
```

It does a getUser on the userService:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UserService {

    private UserDAO userDao;

    public UserDAO getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDao(UserDAO userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        getUserDao().insert(user);
    }

    public User getUser(int id) {
        return getUserDao().load(id);
    }

    public List<User> fetchAllPersons() {
        return getUserDao().selectAll();
    }
}
```

Which uses the userDao to find the entity:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository("userDao")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class UserDAO {

    private static final String SELECT_QUERY = "select u from users";

    @Qualifier(value = "entityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public void insert(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }

    public User load(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(User.class, id);
    }

    public List<User> selectAll() {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(SELECT_QUERY);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> users = (List<User>) query.getResultList();
        return users;
    }

}
```

I have the following spring-config.xml in /src/main/resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mydomain.orm" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="userPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb" />
        <property name="username" value="my_user" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And last but not least the following /src/main/resources/persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="userPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
    <class>com.mydomain.orm.User</class>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What do I need to do to resolve this error?

Honestly though, when this is resolved, I'm probably just going to get a JndiException.  What do you think might also be causing that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I overwrote the version of hibernate-entitymanager to be the same as hibernate-core.  fixed.

Comment: Same here: issue related to different hibernate versions clashing.

Comment: Overrode the version of hibernate-ehcache to be same as hibernate-core to fix same issue which occurred while configuring second level caching using eh-cache.

Answer (score 17):

İf you are using hibernate-core & hibernate-entitymanager in your pom.xml, They must mu same version. I tried this and solved.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

There could be 2 reasons:

1: an appropriate hibernate lib which contains the `JNDIException` is missing within the   classpath

2: There is a version conflict between duplicate hibernate.jars. This can happen if one tries to deploy an application within a JEEContainer (server) which already provides the same library but with a different version.

When the `JNDIException` class can be resolved than your main problem becomes apparent within the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to resolve the ClassNotFoundException first. The error message should give you a better idea about what's wrong.

In order to do that check the version numbers of your hibernate-core lib and your hibernate-entitymanager lib. Also make sure your hibernate version is not conflicting with the jboss hibernate version.