# Spring boot java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project that worked fine for days.
I did not any change on the configuration project but now when I try to launch the project, I have this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at ch.gma.nova.release.rest.Application.main(Application.java:31)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:193)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 7 more
...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:665)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:728)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:707)
    ... 82 more
```

and here is my pom configuration:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>ch.gma.nova.release</groupId>
  <artifactId>RestReleaseApi</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.gma.nova.release</groupId>
      <artifactId>NovaReleaseBatch</artifactId>
      <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
      <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Does anybody had the same issue?

Comment: looks like your buildpath is erroneous: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException`

Comment: Yes, and I found on an another post, that it can be because of a version conflict between hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808649/classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-service-jndi-jndiexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, but I don't know if it is the best one...
I saw that in my dependency NovaReleaseBatch (one of my project) I had a version of Hibernate-core who was not the same as the Hibernate-entitymanager that Spring Boot takes.
So I excluded Hibernate-core from NovaReleaseBatch and I had the same version of Hibernate-entitymanager in my pom.
It works but if somebody has a better way...

Comment: Typical case of dependency conflict.

Comment: It does for the spring boot project iself. If you are mixing several projects together, it highly depend on your build setup and how you package those applications.

Comment: What do you meen "for the spring boot project itself"? You meen that because I add the project NovaReleaseBatch it could have conflict with the transitive dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging)
may be issue can resolve.

Answer (score -1):

I faced similar problem once. Keeping in mind that your project was all working fine by now, and w/o changing any configurations you started to get this error.

Running the application will show you that it can't create the bean, but the real reason for this error is somewhere else which is not pointed out while we run the application. 
To get the error, try to "compile" the project, and it will show you the actual error which is causing this issue. And if it's a maven project, by "compile" here I mean to set your build goal as "compile".

This thing worked for me :)