# Error creating bean with name 'tweetDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am starting a twitter clone with jpa.  I am getting the error that I can't create the tweetDao bean and I am out of ideas.  I am trying to get some output to make sure my implementation of JPA is working but I am failing in trying to build the application with the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tweetDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named jpaApp
```

spring.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jtwitter" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpaApp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userDao" class="com.example.dao.UserDaoImpl" />

<bean id="tweetDao" class="com.example.dao.TweetDaoImpl" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="jpaApp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<description>persistence for JPA</description>
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<class>com.example.model.User</class>
<class>com.example.model.Tweet</class>

<properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jtwitter" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
</properties>
```

TweetDaoImpl

```
@Service("tweetDao")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class TweetDaoImpl implements TweetDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "jpaApp")
    private EntityManager em;

    ...
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>jpa</name>
<description>jpa implementation</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` means you are missing a dependency or, most likely, have mismatched versions. Post your POM or Gradle file.

Comment: @b24tx Root cause says `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/jndi/JndiNameException`. Could be a possible duplicate of [ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808649/classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-service-jndi-jndiexception)

Comment: It's throwing the error when attempting to create the EntityManagerFactory ("emf") due to the exception noted above by @Madhusudana

Comment: @chrylis i added my pom.

Comment: Why are you specifying a version for `hibernate-entitymanager`? (For that matter, why are you explicitly including it at all instead of letting the Boot starter pull it in?)

Comment: @chrylis through desperation of trying to get this to work.  should i not have that as a dependency?

Comment: Try removing it. [`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` includes `hibernate-entitymanager`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.springframework.boot|spring-boot-starter-data-jpa|1.3.3.RELEASE|jar), and it looks like you're adding a conflicting version.

Comment: Why aren't you using spring-data-jpa, when you do have it as dependencs. You could just use spring boot with java based configuration and all this xml is gone.

Comment: i took that out and the other duplicate dependencies and the error changed a little bit, i edited it above.

Comment: @mh-dev i'm still very new to spring(learning it in school) and we have been focusing on xml so far -- i don't know how to do this without xml.

Comment: Ok than I am sorry for you. Just follow the way of your teacher otherwise he will not understand it.